# expo react native apple sign in crashing in TestFlight

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight, apple-sign-in

I am working with expo, react native, and apple sign in. When I work with apple sign in in expo in my simulators everything works fine.

When I push the app to TestFlight and I try to sign in with Apple, the app immediately crashes. No error messages or warnings are thrown, it just closes the app. So I am not sure why this is happening or how to get a log of the crash.

Has anyone else experienced this?

expo --version: 3.21.5
sdk-37.0.1

```
 <AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
  buttonType={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN}
  buttonStyle={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.BLACK}
  cornerRadius={5}
  style={{
    width: Constant.width * 0.92,
    height: 44,
  }}
  onPress={async () => {
    try {
      setAppleLoggingIn(true);
      const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
        requestedScopes: [
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
        ],
      });
      // signed in
      onSignIn(credential);
      setAppleLoggingIn(false);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code === "ERR_CANCELED") {
        // handle that the user canceled the sign-in flow
        setAppleLoggingIn(false);
        return {cancelled: true};
      } else {
        // handle other errors
        setAppleLoggingIn(false);
        return {error: true};
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I was using the wrong service ID. When you push to TestFlight you have to update this from `host.exp.Exponent` to what ever your bundle ID is.